# Unpermitted parameter error in devise registrations controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, devise, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-7

I added a `characteristics` column to my Users table, which is handled by Devise. I need it to be of data type array, which I managed as follows:

`t.text "characteristics", array: true`

I can update the characteristics in my console, but when I try to update them through my form in the browser, I get the following error:

```
Unpermitted parameter: :characteristics.
Context: { controller: Users::RegistrationsController, action: update, request: #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00000001310268b8>, 
params: {"_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Carlos", "last_name"=>"Test", "email"=>"carlostest@gmail.com", "date_of_birth(1i)"=>"2001", 
"date_of_birth(2i)"=>"1", "date_of_birth(3i)"=>"12", "pronouns"=>"he/him", "city_id"=>"1", "summary"=>"I am the sweetest Cuban on this planet.", "characteristics"=>["", "Vegan"], 
"offers_couch"=>"1", "offers_co_work"=>"1", "offers_hang_out"=>"1", "question_one"=>"Laughing with Lissi", "question_two"=>"When Lissi wants me to clean", "question_three"=>"I like privacy",
 "question_four"=>"A good night out", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "couch"=>{"capacity"=>""}, 
"couch_facility"=>{"facility_ids"=>[""]}, "commit"=>"Update", "controller"=>"users/registrations", "action"=>"update"} }
```

My edit form for User looks as follows:

```
<%= f.input :characteristics,
collection: ['Vegan', 'Sunset Drinks', 'Clean Freak', 'No Drinks for Me', 'Party Lover', 'Non-Smoker', 'No Pets', 'Alone Time', 'Sports', 'Exhibitions', 'Political Activism'],
as: :check_boxes,
input_html: {:multiple => true} %>
```

The rest of the form works perfectly, only the characteristics are terrorizing me.

I permitted the params as for all the other fields in the `application_controller.rb`

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:photo, 
:first_name, :last_name, :date_of_birth, :pronouns, :city_id,
 :summary, :offers_couch, :offers_co_work, :offers_hang_out,
 :question_one, :question_two, :question_three, :question_four,
 :characteristics, couch_attributes: [:capacity],
 couch_facility_attributes: [:facility_ids]])
```

As all the other parameters are going through, I am wondering if it has to do with the data type array?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
             
   before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller
```

and make sure you also have the "configure_permitted_parameters" method in your application controller

```
protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
   # User Update parameters.
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys:    [:photo, :first_name, :last_name, :date_of_birth, :pronouns,  :city_id, :summary, :offers_couch, :offers_co_work, :offers_hang_out, :question_one, :question_two, :question_three, :question_four, :characteristics, couch_attributes: [:capacity], couch_facility_attributes: [:facility_ids]])
    end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had all of this implemented already.

Answer (score 0):

What I did in the end to solve this is create two new tables:

- characteristics
- user_characteristics

and the corresponding models. I couldn't make it work with the array.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a special way to permit arrays.

> To declare that the value in params must be an array of permitted
> scalar values map the key to an empty array:
>
> params.permit(:id => [])

Perhaps try:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [
  :other_keys,
  characteristics: [],
  :even_more_keys
])
```